# Facebook Audience Network cause JS-Error Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, facebook, ads

I have integrated the FAN into my page a few days ago and notices a only 5 fill rate. Now it looks like there is a token error caused by this script:

```
  xfbml.ad.js:168 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Strange as the banner sometimes loads but mostly it does not. I did not alter the FB code provided.

This is the URL: http://m.findix.de/kleinanzeigen/fahrzeugmarkt

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: same issue, Mostly it does't show, sometimes it happens